# jQuery - how to find element inside following child?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need the jQuery statement to find ".findme" in this code:

```
$('.clicky').click(function() {
    // the .find() method doesn't do it
    $(this).find('.findme').css('color', 'red');
});

<div class='clicky'></div>
<div class='brother'>
    <div class='findme'>Here I am</div>
</div>
```

I've tried variations on `.find()` and `.next()` and `.children()` and I can't quite work it out....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` in `$(this).find('.findme')` actually refers to the element that was clicked (the div with the class `clicky`.

`.find()` actually searches the descendants of the element you call it on, and since "`findme`" is not within the "`clicky`" div, it doesn't find it.

You should instead use jquery's `.next()` function to get the sibling immediately following the "`clicky`" div (that's the "`brother`"), and then search there for the "`findme`" div.

```
$(this).next().find(".findme").css("color", "red");
```

Answer (score 1):

you may can try to change

```
$('.clicky').click(function() {
    // the .find() method doesn't do it
   $(this).siblings().children('.findme').css('color', 'red');
});
```

and i think you miss the click me inner text for the div

```
<div class='clicky'>click me!!!</div>
<div class='brother'>
  <div class='findme'>Here I am</div>
</div>
```